# Conway's Game of Life (constructor and updating the game)

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, conways-game-of-life

I've been given an assignment dealing with Conway's Game of Life.

I'm having trouble with my CellGrid method and simulateStep method. The probability for being alive doesn't seem to be working and in simulateStep, I'm getting `NullPointerException` errors.

Here is my code:

```
public class CellGrid
{
    private Cell[][] cells;


/**
 * This populates the grid with cells that will be
 * either living or dead (with this probability given by lifeChance)
 * 
 * @param size - grid size
 * @param lifeChance - probability of each cell starting out alive 
 */
public CellGrid(int size, double lifeChance)
{
    cells = new Cell[size][size];
    Random r = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < cells.length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < cells.length; j++)
        {
            Cell c = new Cell();
            double nextVal = r.nextDouble();
            if (nextVal < lifeChance)
            {
                c.setAlive(false);
            }
            else
            {
                c.setAlive(true);
            }
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Iterates the simulation by one step (according to Game of Life rules)
 */
public void simulateStep()
{
    for (int y = 0; y < cells.length; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < cells.length; x++)
        {
            boolean living = cells[y][x].isAlive();
            int count = countNeighbours(y, x);
            boolean result = false;

            if (living && count <= 2)
            {
                result = false;
            }
            if (living && (count == 3 || count == 4))
            {
                result = true;
            }
            if (living && count == 5)
            {
                result = false;
            }
            if (living == true && count > 5)
            {
                result = true;
            }
            if (living == false && count > 5)
            {
                result = true;
            }

            result = cells[y][x].isAlive();
        }
    }
}
```

setAlive method:

```
public void setAlive(boolean alive)
{
    if (isAlive()== true)
    {
        this.alive = false;
    }

    if (isAlive() == false)
    {
        this.alive = true;
    }
}
```

Thank you for all your help!

Comment: Are you able to post the stack trace showing the NPE?

Comment: What is this line of code supposed to do: `double nextVal = r.nextDouble();`? Usually when using the Random class, you will set a range of numbers so that the Random class can choose a number at random.. Also can you please display the `setAlive()` method?

Comment: @ryekayo - if `lifeChance` is a double in the range of [0, 1] then this line determines the initial state of the cell. The whole constructor randomizes the state of the whole plane.

Comment: Your `setAlive` method seems odd. You're not using the parameter, why? I assume you mean something like `toggleAlive()`, i.e. toggle the flag between true and false with each call. In that case you could also do `this.alive = !this.alive;`

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking of it as a toggle-method. Its pretty screwed up :/

Comment: Creating a whole new class "Cell" just containing the alive flag is also kind of a waste.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change `Cell c = new Cell();` to `cells[i][j] = new Cell();` in the constructor.

Comment: ... or at least add `cells[i][j] = c;`